# Long running operation in Flowable.map() blocks all subscribers

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

In my android code, two views need some data from the database that is provided as an `io.reactivex.Flowable` at the same time. One view needs the plain data, but the other one applies a mapping function that involves some IO and takes some time.

The problem is that both subscribers get the data only after the mapping function has terminated. This causes one of the views to be blank while the other one is loading.

```
Flowable<Integer> rxRoomSourceFlowable = Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3).share();

rxRoomSourceFlowable
    .map(integer -> {
        // Some long running operation
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        return integer + "!";
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(str -> System.out.println("Mapped subscriber: " + str));

rxRoomSourceFlowable
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("Plain subscriber: " + integer));
```

The output:

```
Mapped subscriber: 1!
Plain subscriber: 1
Mapped subscriber: 2!
Plain subscriber: 2
Mapped subscriber: 3!
Plain subscriber: 3
```

As you can see the plain subscriber gets notified only after the long running mapping function has terminated, even though the result is completely irrelevant. The order of the calls to `subscribe()` doesn't matter because the subscriptions happen asynchronously anyway.

How to ensure that the plain subscriber gets notified as soon as the data is available without waiting for the mapping function? Is there a different option to change the data inside the `Flowable` than using `map()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`share()` dispatches events in a lockstep fashion, therefore, if one of the subscribers is delayed, the other one won't get items in time. You have to move the offending subscriber off to another thread and let `share` progress:

```
Flowable<Integer> rxRoomSourceFlowable = 
    Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .share();

rxRoomSourceFlowable
.observeOn(Schedulers.io())
.map(integer -> {
    // Some long running operation
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    return integer + "!";
})
.subscribe(str -> System.out.println("Mapped subscriber: " + str));

rxRoomSourceFlowable
.subscribe(integer -> System.out.println("Plain subscriber: " + integer));
```

Comment: Essentially `map()` must be observed on a different thread than `share()`, otherwise it will block execution. Is that correct?